# Can't connect the postgreSQL with psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

It's the first time that I can't find the answer about some tech problems
Here's my problems:

```
>> conn=psycopg2.connect(database="mydb", user="postgres", password="123",port=5432)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

1. My postgreSQL is running
2. My listeningport is 5432 for sure
3. root@lanston-laptop:~# psql -l
   Password:

```
                                       List of databases
         Name      |  Owner   | Encoding | Collation  |   Ctype    |   Access privileges 
    ---------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
     checkdatabase | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
     mydb          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
     postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
     template0     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
     template1     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your libpq, which is used by psycopg2 expects Postgres socket to be in `/var/run/postgresql/` but when you install Postgres from source it is by default it in `/tmp/`.

Check if there is a file `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` instead of `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`. Try:

```
conn=psycopg2.connect(
  database="mydb",
  user="postgres",
  host="/tmp/",
  password="123"
)
```

Comment: This is usually a problem if you are mixing a Debian/Ubuntu-packaged PostgreSQL installation with a hand-compiled one.  Avoid that, unless you are prepared to deal with problems such as these.

Comment: Is there a way to get the socket back to /var/run/postgresql/ ? (I just edited a django source file to get my project to work again for now, but that isn't exactly a nice solution) I didn't install from source by the way...

Comment: I had this problem on OSX when I replaced the built-in Postgres with the Homebrew one. I had to uninstall and reinstall psycopg2 to get it to use the correct libpq.dylib, which -- in turn -- used the correct unix socket path.

Comment: I had this problem after switching to PostgreSQL packages from [PGDG repository](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php). Adding [`--no-binary`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#disabling-wheel-packages-for-psycopg-2-7) to `requirements.txt` and adding `pg_config`'s dir to `PATH` resolved it.

Answer (score 12):

Only this solved my problem,
make a symbolic link to the /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Thanks to, [Sukhjit Singh Sehra - s-postgresql-server-is-running](https://sukhjitsehra.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/is-postgresql-server-is-running-and-accepting-and-issue-with-varpgsql_socket-s-pgsql-5432/)

Comment: Likewise: host="/tmp/" did not fix, but this did.

Comment: @Dhanalal_Bhardwaj


sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
ln: failed to access '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432': Permission denied

Comment: @P_M I am not sure why this is coming even for sudo. You can check 'ln' command specification and other permission related answers. :|

Answer (score 11):

Try change port to 5433 instead of 5432

Comment: This especially works in cases where a new postgres version was installed while a previous version was still running. Since postgres could not use port 5432, it fails up to the next available port, frequently 5433.

Answer (score 11):

I originally intended to make it a comment to [Tometzky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500831/52499)'s answer, but well, I have a lot to say here... Regarding the case where you don't call `psycopg2.connect` directly, but use third-party software.

#### tl;dr

Set `unix_socket_directories` in `postgresql.conf` to `/var/run/postgresql, /tmp`, and restart PostgreSQL.

#### intro

I tried PostgreSQL 9.2 (CentOS 7) and 9.5 (Ubuntu Xenial) from distro repos, PostgreSQL 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10 on CentOS 7 from [PostgreSQL repo](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php), PostgreSQL 9.6, 10 on Ubuntu Xenial from [PostgreSQL repo](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). Among them only 9.3 listens to only `/tmp`:

```
$ systemctl stop postgresql-9.4 && systemctl start postgresql-9.3
$ lsof -aUp $(ps --ppid 1 -o pid= -o comm= | awk '$2 == "postgres" || $2 == "postmaster" {print $1}')
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
postgres 25455 postgres    4u  unix 0xffff9acb23bc5000      0t0 6813995 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

$ systemctl stop postgresql-9.3 && systemctl start postgresql-9.4
$ lsof -aUp $(ps --ppid 1 -o pid= -o comm= | awk '$2 == "postgres" || $2 == "postmaster" {print $1}')
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
postgres 26663 postgres    4u  unix 0xffff9ac8c5474c00      0t0 7086508 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
postgres 26663 postgres    5u  unix 0xffff9ac8c5477c00      0t0 7086510 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

#### `python-psycopg2`

That's not a big deal with `psql`, just a matter of running the matching binary. But if you, for instance, have `python-psycopg2` installed from CentOS's `base` or `update` repo. It links dynamically to `libpq` that OS provides. With 9.3 and 9.4 installed OS provides 9.4's version:

```
$ alternatives --display pgsql-ld-conf
pgsql-ld-conf - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/pgsql-10/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf
/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/postgresql-9.3-libs.conf - priority 930
/usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf - priority 940
Current `best' version is /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf.

$ ls -l /etc/ld.so.conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Feb  7 02:25 postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf -> /etc/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Feb  7 02:25 /etc/alternatives/pgsql-ld-conf -> /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf

$ cat /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf
/usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/
```

But `libpq` that comes with PostgreSQL 9.4 looks for socket in `/var/run/postgresql` as opposed to 9.3:

```
$ strings /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/libpq.so.5 | egrep '/(tmp|var)'
/tmp

$ strings /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/libpq.so.5 | egrep '/(tmp|var)'
/var/run/postgresql
```

The solution comes from postinstall scripts of corresponding packages:

```
$ yum reinstall --downloadonly postgresql94-libs
$ rpm -qp /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/pgdg94/packages/postgresql94-libs-9.4.15-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm --scripts

postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
/usr/sbin/update-alternatives --install /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf   pgsql-ld-conf        /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf 940
/sbin/ldconfig                                                                                 

# Drop alternatives entries for common binaries and man files                                  
postuninstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):                                                       
if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]
  then
    /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --remove pgsql-ld-conf /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf
    /sbin/ldconfig                                                                             
fi
```

Temporarily remove 9.4's alternative:

```
$ alternatives --remove pgsql-ld-conf /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf
$ ldconfig
```

When finished either reinstall `postgresql94-libs`, or add the alternative back:

```
$ alternatives --install /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-pgdg-libs.conf pgsql-ld-conf /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/postgresql-9.4-libs.conf 940
$ ldconfig
```

#### `pip`

If you install `psycopg2` with `pip` on the other hand, it by default installs precompiled package which comes with its own `libpq`, which looks for socket in `/var/run/postgresql`:

```
$ python3.5 -m venv 1
$ . ./1/bin/activate
(1) $ pip install psycopg2

(1) $ python
>>> import psycopg2
>>>Ctrl-Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python

(1) $ pgrep python
26311

(1) $ grep libpq /proc/26311/maps | head -n 1
7f100b8cb000-7f100b90e000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 112980                     /home/yuri/1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-909a53d8.so.5.10

(1) $ strings /home/yuri/1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-909a53d8.so.5.10 | egrep '/(tmp|var)'
/var/run
/var/run/postgresql
```

The solution is to ask `pip` to not install precompiled package, and make `pg_config` of the proper version of PostgreSQL available:

```
$ PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib:$PATH pip install --no-binary psycopg2 psycopg2
```

You can even add `--no-binary` switch to [`requirements.txt`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#disabling-wheel-packages-for-psycopg-2-7):

```
psycopg2==2.7.3.2 --no-binary psycopg2
```

#### `unix_socket_directories`

The easier option though is to make use of [`unix_socket_directories` option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-UNIX-SOCKET-DIRECTORIES):

Answer (score 4):

In my case with a conda installation had to: `sudo ln -s /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Answer (score 3):

a few years later, using the [EnterpriseDB 'graphical' install](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) on OSX 10.8, and pip install of psycopg2 (after linking the /Library/...dylib's [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407995/psycopg2-image-not-found))  i had this same issue.

for me the correct connect command was `conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=DBNAME user=postgres password=PWHERE host=/tmp/')`

Answer (score 1):

Having this happen to me after a `brew upgrade`, I googled for `brew .s.PGSQL.5432`.

Per the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27925369/4960855) I ran the following:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And got:

```
2019-10-29 17:43:30.860 IST [78091] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2019-10-29 17:43:30.860 IST [78091] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 10, which is not compatible with this version 11.5.
```

I googled that FATAL error and per the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745770/4960855) I ran:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

put vpc_access_connector:
name: project//locations/us-central1/connectors/

and host :'/cloudsql/::

It should work for private Ip postgresql on gcp

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
cd /etc/postgresql/13/main
vi pg_hba.conf
```

Change the line after this

Database administrative login by Unix domain socket

local   all             postgres                                ***peer***

To

local   all             postgres                                ***md5***

Then execute following commands

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql

sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

> Then run the python program then it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

> This issue arises because sometimes postgres connects on
> localhost-5433 instead of localhost-5432 as some other application
> might be using that 5432 port.

Try this:

```
con = pg2.connect(database='db', user='postgres', password='',port=5433)
```