# Can't connect to Postgres database with Bitnami Django stack

Tags: django, postgresql, bitnami

I keep running into the problem of not being able to connect to the database:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
```

`Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket “/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432”?`

I did some reading and it seems like it’s a quite common problem that most people fix by checking that the port is correct, ie from changing 5432 to 5433 in their setup.py. But this does not seem to be my problem – in the /opt/bitnami/postgresql directory i see .s.PGSQL.5432. I can log into psql and it seems to work correctly. I think the default database name is postgresql, but i also tried it with the one called djangostack and it didn’t work either. My database information in Django's setting.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2', #'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'postgres',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'bitnami',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

I look in the /tmp/ directory and there isn’t anything there, hidden or otherwise. Is there supposed to be? Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong? I stupidly overwrote the original example project so I can’t see what the settings were there.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Sorry I should add that I'm running the Bitnami Django 1.3 AMI on ec2, as seen at the bottom of [this link](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack).

Comment: Did you install postgresql? Did you start it? Can you connect to it with a client like pgsql or pgAdmin?

Comment: Yes, it is installed by default with the AMI, and I can connect to it with psql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the PostgreSQL socket is in `/opt/bitnami/postgresql` but your `libpq` (the C library that `psycopg2` wraps) is looking for the socket in `/tmp`, right? Try changing the [`HOST` setting to point at the proper socket location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500332/cant-connect-the-postgresql-with-psycopg2):

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE':   'postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME':     'postgres',
    'USER':     'postgres'
    'PASSWORD': 'bitnami',
    'HOST':     '/opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432', # <-------
    'PORT':     '5432',
}
```

[Or this](http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/djangostack/topics/psycopg2-operationalerror-could-not-connect-to-server-2):

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE':   'postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME':     'postgres',
    'USER':     'postgres'
    'PASSWORD': 'bitnami',
    'HOST':     '/opt/bitnami/postgresql', # <-------
    'PORT':     '5432',
}
```

And you might want to change the the PostgreSQL password too.

Comment: According to [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES) the socket-as-hostname feature only works for MySQL. Set HOST to 127.0.0.1 instead to bypass sockets.

Comment: @Mel: The documentation often presents a simplified version of reality. I found a few examples that indicate that socket-as-hostname also works with psycopg2. The docs seem to be a little ambiguous about what happens when you use a path for the host with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks mu, setting "host" to "/opt/bitnami/postgresql" fixed it.

Comment: If you are using the BitNami AMI setting 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Hostname to `localhost`

```
   DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
            "NAME": "DB",
            "USER": "USER",
            "PASSWORD": "PASS",
            "HOST": "localhost",
            "PORT": "5432",
        }
    }
```

Also, don't connect it with default postgres user. [Create a new one](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/django/configuration/create-database/).

Answer (score 0):

Restart postgresql by using the command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart postgresql
```

it worked for me

[image]