# could not connect to postgresql server django lightsail

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, amazon-lightsail

I keep running into the problem of not being able to connect to the database:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

its my list of databases:

```
                                  List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

and its the postgres config section of `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '/opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass'
    }
}
```

I also tried answers to these two questions

- [Can't connect to Postgres database with Bitnami Django stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102232/cant-connect-to-postgres-database-with-bitnami-django-stack/6102679)
- [Can't connect the postgreSQL with psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500332/cant-connect-the-postgresql-with-psycopg2)
  but none of them helped.

here is `pip list`:

```
 psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
```

my debug mode is false:

```
DEBUG = False
```

and in allowed hosts I have my private IP:

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion in Bitnami documentation.
The file traceback says it can't find the file: `.s.PGSQL.5432`
This file is actually located in `/tmp` folder. (don't ask)

If you change your settings.py to have a `/tmp` folder as a Host it will work:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        # 'HOST': '/opt/bitnami/postgresql',
        'HOST': '/tmp/',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234'
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /opt/bitnami/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

but I haven't tested it.