# Python, Flask + SQLAlchemy - query not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I've got the following Python code

```
app = Flask(__name__)      
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://my_user_name:@localhost:5432/my_db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route("/submit_signup_email", methods=["POST"])
def submit_signup_email():
  email = request.form["email"]
  created_timestamp = int(time.time())
  signup            = Signup(email, created_timestamp)
  db.session.add(signup)
  db.session.commit()

  # not working...
  test = Signup.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
```

Which works fine and I can check that a row has been inserted correctly in my DB.

But if I run this code after "db.session.commit()".....

```
test = Signup.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
```

I get the following error.

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) could not connect to server: No
>   such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting
>   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I'm not sure what the problem is, my Signup model looks like this in "models.py"

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app, db

class Signup(db.Model):
  __tablename__     = "signups"
  id                = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  email             = db.Column(db.String)
  created_timestamp = db.Column(db.Integer)

  def __init__(self, email, created_timestamp):
    self.email             = email
    self.created_timestamp = created_timestamp

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.email
```

Comment: How did you connect the DB? Did you connect it before the query?

Comment: I've added the connection statements

Comment: Did you import the db before the query?

Comment: "db" is defined in the same file. It's already there, isn't it?

Comment: Try to put the query right after commit, and see whether it works or not.

Comment: That's exactly what I did actually. I've edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Is your Singup class inherited from the same db?

Comment: Yes. Added the "signup" model on my post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31170/discussion-between-waitingkuo-and-ericbae)

Answer (score 0):

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
db.app = app

init_app(app) : 
This callback can be used to initialize an application for the use with this database setup. Never use a database in the context of an application not initialized that way or connections will leak.

and "from app import app,db" is incorrect

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a PostfreSql Problem, [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990023/postgresql-operationalerror-could-not-connect-to-server). Maybe you should try to restart your server.

#### EDIT

After seeing your code (in the chat room), the problem might be "Circular Import". Try to prevent that