# Psycopg2 image not found

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, psycopg2

Trying to setup postgres with the postgres mac app and hit this error, which I haven't been able to solve. Any thoughts?

```
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Craig/pyenv/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libpq.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 90):

```
$ sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
```

I encountered this error while working on Django.
I have it working on virtualenv with Django==1.3 but not on Django==1.5 where I have to issue the commands above.

In OS X El Capitan you can't do these links without disabling system protection but it works well if you link to /usr/local/lib

Comment: This answer was the only one that worked for me that didn't screw up other systems like Mercurial etc. Looks like it's a known issue: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/109#issuecomment-18387546

Comment: And for those of you using Heroku's Postgres.app --

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib`
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib`

Comment: In case you've already created a symbolic link from a previous version, be sure to remove it before you create a new one.
    `sudo rm /usr/lib/libssl.X.X.X.dylib`
    `sudo rm /usr/lib/libcrypto.X.X.X.dylib`
Then add the new links following philippinedev answer. (Be sure to have the right version of files in your path of course)

Comment: I symlink into `/usr/local/lib` just because it feels safer and less likely to mess with the system than `/usr/lib`.  Works just as well.

Comment: Just a reminder that when you create the symlinks, you have to explicitly define the path to the file you're linking to. I forgot this, and spent forever trying to figure out why I was getting weird errors in psycopg2. The reason was that I had just cd'ed into the directory with libssl, and typed './libssl.1.0.0...'. This created the symlink to the literal string ./libssl.1.0.0..., which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: @JoeShaw's comment is mandatory in OS X El Capitan. You'll get a `ln: /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib: Operation not permitted` error otherwise. This is due to "rootless" mode. More info here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196224/unix-ln-s-command-not-permitted-in-osx-el-capitan-beta3

Comment: Can confirm `sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib; sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib` works for 9.5 Postgres.app

Comment: @philippinedev I get ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/Desktop/foo/bar/one/blue/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib . Any advice?

Answer (score 52):

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

works like a charm!

Discussion on source+wheel distribution (pyscopg2) vs a separate binary distribution (psycopg2-binary): https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2Bmi_8bd6kJHLTGkuyHSnqcgDrJ1uHgQWvXCKQFD3tPQBUa2Bw%40mail.gmail.com

Explanation on the decision to release psycopg2-binary: http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2018/02/08/psycopg-274-released/

However, there are reports of psycopg2-binary not satisfying psycopg2 dependencies. More discussion here: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/674

Comment: When answering an older question with existing answers it is useful  to explain what differentiates your answer from the existing answers. For really old questions it is also useful to indicate if the answer relies on newer versions of the software.

Answer (score 18):

I found a solution that worked for me when dealing with a similar issue on rails. Add the following to your .bash_profile, .bash_rc, or equivalent:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(Assuming you installed Postgres.app in the default location). Then restart your terminal session and try again.

Exporting to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH directly can cause serious problems with other apps that depend on it, but using the fallback path avoids these problems.

See also: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/109#issuecomment-18387546

**EDIT**: It seems that setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH causes an error when you try to run psql. To fix this, you can add the following two lines to your .bash_profile:

```
alias psql="(. ~/.bash_profile; unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH; psql)";
```

This is assuming that you're using bash and that your .bash_profile is located in your home directory. If that's not the case (or if you're using a .bashrc or other environment setup instead of .bash_profile) change the `~/.bash_profile` part of the command to the path to your environment setup script.

The aliased command basically starts a subshell which does not effect your current bash environment. So when it unsets the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH variable, it's only temporary. After you exit psql the environment variable will be set again.

Comment: Minor tweaks for a virtualenv; I added this line to my `postactivate`: `export "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"`, and when installing used this command: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib pip install psycopg2`

Answer (score 17):

This happened to me after upgrading Postgresql, and after installing psycopg2 in my virtualenv. Reinstalling (re-building) worked for me.

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading postgresql.app version 9.3 to 9.5 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading from Postgres 9.6 to 12.1. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me once I cleaned pip cache (`pip cache purge`) - the built version in cache was still pointing to the old libssl path.

Answer (score 11):

This problem cost me the whole morning to solve. I found the discussion on http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/11/11/links-about-building-psycopg-mac-os-x/ really helpful. Thanks to Jurie's answer, the solution to my problem (in Mac) is as below:

1. Install openssl 1.0.0 using brew:

   ```
    brew install openssl
   ```
2. using the following command:

   ```
   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/**1.0.1x**/lib
   ```

   replace **1.0.1x** part with your current version. For me it is 1.0.1h.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: After one day, I found that the second command has to be entered every time when needing to connect to database, so not a permanent solution to this problem.

Comment: Setting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable when executing the command also works: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib/ python manage.py migrate

Comment: add `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/**1.0.1x**/lib` to your environment activate script (e.g. ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/activate)

Comment: you can also add the command in `~/.bash_profile` and it will work everytime without having to enter it again and again

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou, this would cause ssl import failure as can be seen from this issue: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/mVvbFVFyUjE

Answer (score 10):

In your bash environment before you load it, try this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/lib
```

..replacing the 'x.y' with the version on your system.

..be aware that setting this in your bash profile can interfere with other programs, as KindOfGuy noted.

..of course, if you're not running it from a bash prompt, you'll have to set up your environment in whatever way pyenv lets you.  ..you could even edit pyenv itself and place that at the top.

Another alternative is to put this in a python script which runs before you attempt to import psycopg2:

```
import os
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/lib'
```

..again, replacing 'x.y' with the version on your system in /Library/PostgreSQL.

Comment: Nothing... Though I checked out that folder `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/` and the only item inside was a locked folder named 'data'. I imagine there should be other items, right?

Comment: running the export from bash profile caused trouble elsewhere, but I stuck `os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/lib'` into manage.py which worked a charm. Will still need to do this in all projects, but this will help me until the issue gets sorted some other way.

Comment: On behalf of [ctbailey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/943189/ctbailey) : *Here's an updated path for version 9.3 of Postgres.app : `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`*.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this issue when I upgraded from postgres.app 9.4 to 9.5 on el capitan.

The other solutions will not work (easily) in el capitan because of the system lock on certain directories, meaning the symbolic link solution will be less accessible/ideal for most.

This leaves the fallback variable.  The current answer points to the wrong directory.  I am guessing the dylibs directory has changed since 2013.

So, here is the latest fallback directory that works for me:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thank you! A similar issue to that in the question was driving me absolutely batty, but prepending Postgres' `lib` to `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Under Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), `/usr/lib` is read only for root user.
You'll get a `ln: /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib: Operation not permitted error`
You need to use `/usr/local/lib` instead of `/usr`.

```
$ sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
$ sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem I am using macOS executing `pip install psycopg2-binary` did wonder for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Big picture, the problem is that a required library couldn’t be found. You can alter where `psycopg2` looks for `libssl` using Apple’s [open source compiler tools](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/), `otool` and `install_name_tool`. These ship with OS X, and manual pages are available with `man <command>`.

Change into the `psycopg2` module directory mentioned in the error message. Once there:

```
$ otool -L _psycopg.so
    ...
    @executable_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    ...
```

This lists the libraries `_psycopg2.so` will look for. You can change where it’ll look with `install_name_tool`:

```
$ install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib _psycopg.so
```

You’ll need to adjust for where you have `libssl.1.0.0.dylib`, of course. The example I gave is the default Homebrew path, but you might have it from Anaconda and/or the PostgreSQL app bundle. (`brew install openssl` if you don’t have it yet.) You’ll also likely need to repeat for libcrypto.

Executing this change may fail depending on how `_psycopg2.so` was built. If that happens, you could probably build the module yourself with custom library paths, but I won’t get into that.

This approach has the advantage of being narrower, and thus less risky, than the approach (given in other answers here) of linking libssl 1.0.0 into `dyld`’s search paths (either through `ln -s` or setting a `DYLD_*` environment variable). (See warnings against these approaches in a [pair](https://superuser.com/a/721564/82020) of [discussions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/18990#issuecomment-15961688) and [some code](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/formula_support.rb#L28). Learn more about `dyld` through `man dyld`.) It has the disadvantage of needing to be repeated for each copy of `psycopg2`. Choose your own adventure.

Disclaimer: Most of the content in this answer is from knowledge I cobbled together in one day. I am no expert.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution that worked for me

```
sudo cp /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib 

sudo cp /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

Replace this part '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/' depending upon the location where psql is installed on your machine. Command to find where psql is installed :`which psql`

UPDATE FROM COMMENTS: 
On OSX 10.11 (El Capitan), you can no longer copy files to /usr/lib. Use /usr/local/lib

Comment: Re: @MitMehta's solution: On OSX 10.11 (El Capitan), you can no longer copy files to /usr/lib. Use /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Why not use the available 'latest' symlink in Postgres.app and copy to both /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib like: sudo ln -sf /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib/libssl.dylib {/usr/lib,/usr/local/lib}; sudo ln -sf /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib/libcrypto.dylib {/usr/lib,/usr/local/lib}

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the postgresql client package, so I installed them with brew and that fixed this issue for me.

```
brew update
brew doctor
brew install postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error because of upgrading Postgres.app (from 9.3 to 9.4).

The solution was to delete the pip cache wheels because they were pointing to Postgres.app version 9.3.

I've found the according psycopg wheel cache files this way

```
grep -r psycopg ~/.pip/cache
```

and deleted the directory I've found with the last command.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was to install psycopg2 with the "no-binary" option set, which tells psycopg2 to use the system libssl.

By default psycopg2 uses its own version of libssl and it seemed to keep a dependency on an old version of the library which no longer existed after my upgrade.

See the [psycopg2 install docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html) for more detail about the no-binary option.

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install --no-binary :all: psycopg2
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***In case if you are working on python/django with virtual environment***

Worked for me for the following Version

- MacOS Catalina 10.5.2
- python 3.7.3
- Django 3.0.2
- psycopg2==2.8.4
- virtualenv 16.6.0
- pip 19.3.1
- postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.2

> 3 Steps Solutions

- Delete Existing Virtual Environment
- Create New Virtual Environemnt again
- Install Dependencies again

Answer (score 0):

Did you install psycopg2? You need it in order to integrate python with postgresql.

Comment: Yup, it's installed. I'm running a pyenv, might that affect things?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue with mysql. The library requested is is failing to load `/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib`

However, in this directory, there is a later version of the library:
`/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib`

I am working in a virtualenvwrapper and have attempted to reinstall all of the previously install dependencies to no avail. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what worked for me. I was using Anaconda with jupyter. The following did work:

```
 DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib  jupyter notebook
```

But then caused later issues importing another library (plotly). After playing around with pip, I realised I should probably be using conda instead and the following seemed to fix everything.

```
conda install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `psycopg2` using `pip install psycopg2 --upgrade` to the latest version, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

try finding the file or files  libssl.1.0.0.dylib and copy them to your '/usr/local/lib/'
for me the origin was, '/Library/PostgreSQL/11/lib/' ,(change the version to yours)
alternatively you may copy all to '/usr/local/lib/'
go to the origin and type:
sudo cp * /usr/local/lib/ to copy all files. 
I found the solution and changed it to solve mine https://oscarvalles.wordpress.com/2017/03/24/dlopenlibrary-not-loaded-libssl-dylib-fail-to-import-psycopg2-in-virtualenv/

Answer (score 0):

Use `psycopg2-binary` instead

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering similar problem while running my **Django** server with **postgreSQL** as DB. I fixed it by relying on following steps, I am making use of conda to take care of virtual enviroments.

Create a new virtual enviroment I named it `newenv`

1 - `conda create --name newenv`

2 - `conda activate newenv`

3 - `pip install -r requirements.txt`

4 - `python manage.py runserver`

Afterwards It worked like a charm :).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem because when I built lambda function for AWS with `pip install psycopg2-binary -t .` on my computer where I had locally installed python3.8 but for lambda on AWS I chose python3.9. When I switch to same version all started to work again.