# Attempting to setup Postgresql with Python - psycopg2 is installed but erroring

Tags: python, django, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to add a database to a new python app. Postgres is my db of choice, it works on my machine with many rails apps, is up and running, and I have created a db for my project.

Troubleshooting so far:

> pip install psycopg2

render looks appropriate:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

ok, testing it

> python

```
>> import psycopg2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Looks like a module problem.

In my bash_profile I am exporting the correct version of psql:

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin:"$PATH"
```

My database settings shouldn't matter as it fails the test before I start running a server but:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'firstBlog',
        'USER': 'ML',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Of course, attempting to run the server will also crash it.

Brew Doctor is not turning up any errors. Any ideas where I can continue to troubleshoot?

Comment: Could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407995/psycopg2-image-not-found

Comment: What does "which pip" and "which python" tell you? I think you have a confusion between your system python stuff and brew packages. And what is your PATH and PYTHONPATH?

Comment: You should probably use virtualenv if you don't already. Simplifies a lot of this stuff and prevents you from polluting the system python installation.

Comment: $ which pip
'/usr/local/bin/pip'

$ which python
'/usr/local/bin/python'

If I go back to follow the instructions [link] ( http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html ) it errors, so it looks like I'll need to troubleshoot virtualenv before postgres.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @karthikr , the solution by stephenalexbrowne on the page you linked worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it seems that my environmental variables weren't exporting psql properly for Django. I found a solution on the page linked by @karthikr that solved it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740552/2967262