# Unable to install psycopg2 on OSX Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, psycopg2, osx-elcapitan

This is what I am getting:

```
Adnans-MBP:~ AdnanAhmad$ easy_install psycopg2
Searching for psycopg2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/psycopg2/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/7b/a8/dc2d50a6f37c157459cd18bab381c8e6134b9381b50fbe969997b2ae7dbc/psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz#md5=4a392949ba31a378a18ed3e775a4693f
Best match: psycopg2 2.6.2
Processing psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/d3/t5c58nx570ggzzknhm4zpjnw0000gn/T/easy_install-66rCLK/psycopg2-2.6.2/setup.cfg
Running psycopg2-2.6.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/d3/t5c58nx570ggzzknhm4zpjnw0000gn/T/easy_install-66rCLK/psycopg2-2.6.2/egg-dist-tmp-Vu8qsu
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using `PostgreSql.app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, since you are using anaconda anyways, might as well take advantage of their binary packages! They have one for `PostgreSQL`! just type

```
conda install psycopg2
```

Comment: Seems it does install but now I get error: `Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: I would try `pip uninstall psycopg2 && conda uninstall psycopg2` and try to re-install the whole thing! if your error actually starts with `//anaconda/..` that looks strange to me.

Comment: this looks similar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407995/psycopg2-image-not-found

Comment: Saw this but sadly I don't have such path available at all

Comment: check if you got that file at all.. `find / -name _psycopg.so`. then if you do, put a soft link in the place where it tries to find it

Comment: `/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
/anaconda/pkgs/psycopg2-2.6.2-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so`

Comment: well try this at your own risk:
`rm -rf /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so && ln -s /anaconda/pkgs/psycopg2-2.6.2-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-pack‌​ages/psycopg2/_psyco‌​pg.so /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so `

Comment: I had to link up PostgreSQL Librares in /usr/local and it worked