# Postgres - FATAL: database files are incompatible with server

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

After restarting my MacBook Pro I am unable to start the database server:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I checked the logs and the following line appears over and over again:

```
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.2, which is not compatible with this version 9.0.4.
```

9.0.4 was the version that came preinstalled on the mac, 9.2[.4] is the version I installed via Homebrew.

As mentioned, this used to work before the restart, so it can't actually be a compiling issue. I also re-ran `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` and the file still exists.

Comment: How do you start postgres?  Are you sure your startscript points to the new version?  Because based on the error messages I think both versions are installed side by side now.

Comment: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start` - and the response is `server starting`

Comment: When you search for files named `pg_ctl`  I'm pretty sure you're going to find 2 copies.  And the one that matches `which pg_ctl` will be the old version, and the other will be the new version.

Comment: running `pg_ctl --version` gives `pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4`

Comment: And yet that copy of pg_ctl seems to be starting a 9.0.4 postmaster...  Did you stop postgres before upgrading via homebrew?  As it stands you should probably ensure all postgres processes are stopped and redo the installation of 9.2.4

Comment: `ps aux | grep postgres` yields nothing, and as I mentioned, it used to work just fine before - so I doubt that I messed up the installation. You think a reinstallation is the best way to go?

Comment: yes, as right now a 9.2.4 pg_ctl appears to be starting a 9.0.4 backend, and that's definitely a bad situation!  You could try to untangle the mess manually, but reinstalling on top of the preexisting mix of versions somehow seems easier and more bulletproof to do (and as you seem to have just initialized you datadir, your db is empty anyways, so nothing will be lost).

Comment: the error exists even after reinstallation... I am at my wits end :-(

Comment: Apple's insane decision to pre-install PostgreSQL and put their pre-installed version on the default PATH just seems to get worse with time...

Comment: @CraigRinger really? Apple preinstalls postgresql?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Sure did then. I think now they've moved it to bundle it inside `Server.app` and hidden it to use a non-default port and unix socket directory. Finally!

Answer (score 788, accepted):

If you recently **upgraded** postgres to latest version, you can run the below command to upgrade your postgres data directory retaining all data:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

The above command is taken from the output of `brew info postgres`

Note: this won't work for upgrading from 14 to 15 as of recent testing. For postgres version > 14, you should use `pg_upgrade` directly to upgrade your clusters.

Comment: This worked like a charm, however, after it worked, it introduced a second error, remember to upgrate the db created by initdb using `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` then restart postgres

Comment: Worked on 9.5 to 11 as well. Kudos for also showing how to use `brew info`.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me after upgrade my postgres from 10 to 11

Comment: From 10 to 11.5. You are a life saver. <3

Comment: Works for 11 to 12 as well.

Comment: Works from 9.5 to 12 !!

Comment: Works for 10 to 12.2 as well :)

Comment: Upgrading from 9.2 to 12.3 I’m getting this error when running the above command (which Homebrew also showed to me): `Error: No postgresql 9.2.* version installed!`

Comment: Can verify that this works fine when moving from 12 to 13 as well.

Comment: This is one of those "So we meet again" answers I have to look up every 6-12 months.

Comment: Confirmed this still worked great upgrading from version 11 to 13.

Comment: This worked for me with only one caveat: I had to make sure that the postgresql homebrew process was off first. (brew services stop postgresql). Then I would execute, brew postgresql-upgrade-database -- and then of course I would run brew services start postgresql. If I don't do this I get this error, "lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists", which I see in these logs "cat /usr/local/var/log/pg_upgrade_server.log"

Comment: This is upgrading the entire world of packages from my mac which I'm not even aware of. Woah! I hope that my actual problem is solved though.

Comment: Works for 13 => 14 as well.

Comment: Oh and don't forget to `brew services stop postgresql` before

Comment: "`Upgrading postgresql data from 13 to 14 failed`" : why might that be? :( When I try to run the server, I get the following errors: "`FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server`", "`DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.1.`", "`FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists`"

Comment: @payne - try deleting the lock file "postmaster.pid" and try again? before doing this, please have a backup

Comment: For me this only worked in a normal terminal window, not my iTerm2 session.  Go figure.

Answer (score 250):

If you are looking for the nuclear option (delete all data and get a fresh database), you can do:

`rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8`

and then you'll need to `rake db:setup` and `rake db:migrate` from your Rails app to get setup again.

Comment: If the above still doesn't work (which was the case for me), try giving a new data directory name to initdb, e.g. /usr/local/var/postgres95.

Comment: btw, immediately after this you'll probably need to run `createuser -s your_rails_app` to create the rails' postgres user. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/postgresql-error-fatal-role-username-does-not-exist/25263322

Comment: Or if you're nervous like me and want to go nuclear but keep a backup in the bunker just in case, do `mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres_backup && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` instead!

Answer (score 42):

Try this : 
https://gist.github.com/joho/3735740

It worked perfectly for me.
In the end it also generates you 2 bash scripts to check your DB and remove the old cluster.
Really Awesome.

see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgupgrade.html to understand more.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with migration from 9.4 to 9.5.

Comment: Also worked for me with migration from 9.3.4 to 9.5.2.

Comment: Here are the steps for updating 9.5.5 to 9.6.1 using Homebrew (macOS): https://gist.github.com/giannisp/b53a76047b07751ed3ade3c1db1d2c51

Comment: That should definitely be the best answer!! And no data loss.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon

Answer (score 14):

Found on internet, this solution work fine for me.

When I tried to start postgresql server after upgrade to OS X 10.10 Yosemite, I encountered with a next problem:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Okay, lets take a look into server logs:

`cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

```
FATAL: database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.2, which is not compatible with this version 9.3.5.
```

So, we need to follow a few steps after upgrade postgresql:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist

mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres92

brew update

brew upgrade postgresql

initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8

pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres92 -D /usr/local/var/postgres

cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres92
```

That's it.

Comment: I have used the above steps to upgrade from 9.53 to 10.0. The pg_upgrade command has upgraded a bit. The new command is pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/bin/ -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.0/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres95 -D /usr/local/var/postgres

Comment: better solution below

Answer (score 12):

If you want to keep the previous version of postgres, use `brew switch`:

```
$ brew info postgresql

postgresql: stable 10.5 (bottled), HEAD
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with:
  postgres-xc (because postgresql and postgres-xc install the same binaries.)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3 (3,259 files, 36.6MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2017-07-09 at 22:15:41
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5 (1,705 files, 20.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-11-04 at 15:13:13

$ brew switch postgresql 9.6.3
$ brew services stop postgresql
$ brew services start postgresql
```

Otherwise, consider this brew command to migrate existing data: `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`. Check out [the source code](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/cmd/brew-postgresql-upgrade-database.rb).

Answer (score 11):

As @Gowtham mentioned, you can solve this problem by executing  a brew command

`brew postgresql-upgrade-database`
The above command is taken from the output of `brew info postgres`

However, don't forget to stop the postgres service before executing it, use the following command:
`brew services stop postgresql

you may have to start the service again.

So the final order of commands are:

```
brew services stop postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful

Comment: PS, don't forget to CLOSE your virtual environment first, if you're using one

Answer (score 9):

This can also occur when running a new Postgres in Docker, and your old volume isn't updated.

If you don't need to keep your data easiest is to clear the old volumes in the docker folder, in Linux that's here:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes
```

Comment: what if you need to keep your data?

Answer (score 7):

Similar to these answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745770/534761), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66401549/534761)), my Postgres database files were incompatible to my Postgres version after upgrading to `postgresql 13.3`.

Unfortunately, upgrading my Postgres data directory failed.

```
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database
...
Setting next OID for new cluster
*failure*

Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_utility.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.
Failure, exiting
Error: Upgrading postgresql data from 12 to 13 failed!
==> Removing empty postgresql initdb database...
==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/postgres...
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_upgrade -r -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.7/bin -B /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old -D /usr/local/var/postgres -j 8` exited with 1.
```

My workaround for this was to reinstall `postgresql 12.7`.

```
$ brew reinstall postgresql@12
$ brew services start postgresql@12
```

Answer (score 3):

It happened for me when I was trying to start Postgres12 with postgres11 mounted volume. Just deleting the mounted volume for postgres11 and restart worked for me.

Previously I was using:

```
docker run -d --name my_database -v /Users/champ/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 54320:5432 postgres:11
```

I deleted /Users/champ/postgres and restarted postgres 12, using

```
docker run -d --name my_database -v /Users/champ/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 54320:5432 postgres:12
```

Answer (score 3):

`brew info postgres` will give you hints Like `To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:`

So in my case removing the old one `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres.old` and upgrading the DB `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`

Answer (score 2):

A stale `postmaster.pid` file caused this for me.

Simply navigate to your postgres directory `/Users/st/Library/Application Support/Postgres/`, for me, that's:

```
cd '/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-10'
```

Then delete the file `postmaster.pid`. Restart postgres and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

To me works with this command:

```
brew install --build-from-source postgresql@12
```

Then started Postgres:

```
brew services start postgresql@12
```

You can also check the port *5432* is listen:

```
netstat -nl |grep 5432
```

Comment: This was useful for me, turns out my issue had to do with conflicting versions of Postgres installed on my Mac

Answer (score 1):

It's 2024 and this answer is for some non-computer nerds who are trying to install Postgres again.

if you're receiving this message that means there's already folder in you programFiles with name Postgress exist because you might install before and didn't uninstall properly.

what you can do here is go to `C --> Program files --> Postgress`
and delete and then again try to install it'll work remember to delete anything nfrom c you need to have administrator consent.