# Having an error message while trying to download postgresql version 17.6

Tags: postgresql

[There was an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DQsP.jpg)

Trying to download postgresql version 17.6 and this what happened and I got an error message saying the existing data directory is not compatible with the server. What should I do next (CATALOG VERSION PG_VERSION)

Comment: Did you even try to research a resolution for this? Also, sql server <> postgresql, they are completely different products.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822974/postgres-fatal-database-files-are-incompatible-with-server

Comment: What does a download for PostgreSQL have to do with (Microsoft) SQL Server?

Comment: There is no Postgres 17.6 version. The latest release is 16.0.  As to the error you cannot install a new major version over top of an existing version. You need to add to your question **as text** more information about the steps you are taking and the actual Postgres versions you are working with.

Comment: Why do you think PostgreSQL version 17.6 already exists? My best guess will be that it will take another 3 years to get to that version.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the same major PostgreSQL version you find in `PG_VERSION` in the data directory.