# Unable to connect to postgres database with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to psql server but unfortunately always receiving this error. (windows, vs code, python 3.7.4, psycopg2, postgresql 11)

Code part:

```py
import psycopg2
import json
data = json.load(open("data.json"))


conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "dictfly", user = "postgres", password = "postgres", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
print("Opened database successfully")
cur = conn.cursor()
for pair in data:
    cur.execute("ISERT INTO dict_tables VALUES (pair, data[pair])")

conn.commit()
print("Records created successfully")
conn.close()
```

Terminal

```
PS C:\mysite\dict> python jsonTOpgsql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsonTOpgsql.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "dictfly", user = "postgres", password = "postgres0208", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
  File "C:\Users\uafir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
PS C:\mysite\dict>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'database' is not a valid keyword argument for psycopg2.connect(). Try using the keyword 'dbname' instead:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="dictfly", user = "postgres", password = "postgres", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
```

Source: [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html?highlight=connect#psycopg2.connect)

Comment: Tried, both are giving the same output.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500332/cant-connect-the-postgresql-with-psycopg2) post?